# Integration of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$?

I have tried *integration by parts*, but it is a never ending series with no specific general term.

PS: It is indefinite integration.

Comment: Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: There exists no elementary solution of this integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no indefinite integral expressible in terms of elementary functions. A special function has to be defined for this purpose, and it is known as the [Logarithmic Integral Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

Note that many, many seemingly elementary functions do not have indefinite integrals that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Another famous example is $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Just curious : how can we prove that there is no existing function that matches ?

Comment: @ArnaudMégret This might help. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral